# Error when compiling XML-Parser-2.44 with Perl

Tags: perl, lfs

When trying to `perl Makefile.pl` XML-Parser-2.44 while chrooted in LFS, I get this error:

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite LWP::UserAgent 0 not found.
Have /tools/lib/perl5/5.26.0
Want /tools/lib/perl5/5.26.0/x86_64-linux
Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [5.26.0]
Config says: [x86_64-linux]
This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.
Have /tools/lib/perl5/5.26.0
Want /tools/lib/perl5/5.26.0/x86_64-linux
Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [5.26.0]
Config says: [x86_64-linux]
This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.
ERROR from evaluation of /sources/XML-Parser-2.44/Expat/Makefile.PL: Failed to opendir '/tools/lib/perl5/5.26.0/x86_64-linux/CORE' to find header files: No such file or directory at /tools/lib/perl5/5.26.0/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm line 3027.
```

Comment: How exactly was `perl` built?

Comment: This link explains how perl was built:

Comment: http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/perl.html

Comment: Those notes indicate a build prefix of `/usr` while your errors instead say `/tools` so you've done unknown things; find out where your original build put the `CORE` directory and why whatever it is you've done since has rendered that directory unfindable.

Comment: I just need to point perl to the /usr/bin directory for compiling, but I don't know how

Answer (score -1):

Just add this line: `/usr/local/lib` to this file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf` and re-install Perl.

```
$ echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
```